# How to persist JSR 310 java.time.LocalDateTime in JPA with Hibernate using usertype

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, usertype, java-time

I'm trying to persist java.time.LocalDateTime in Java 8 in JPA with Hibernate using usertype.

I've a property annotated as following.

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threetenbp.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private java.time.LocalDateTime createdDateTime;
```

And I've added dependencies for usertype as following.

```
compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.extended:3.2.0.GA'
compile 'org.threeten:threetenbp:0.9'
```

However, I'm getting following exceptions

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate custom type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threetenbp.PersistentLocalDateTime
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.custom(TypeFactory.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.custom(TypeFactory.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.byClass(TypeFactory.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.heuristicType(TypeResolver.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:86)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:764)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.utils.reflection.TypeHelper.getTypeArguments(TypeHelper.java:73)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractSingleColumnUserType.<init>(AbstractSingleColumnUserType.java:41)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractParameterizedUserType.<init>(AbstractParameterizedUserType.java:24)
    at org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threetenbp.PersistentLocalDateTime.<init>(PersistentLocalDateTime.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.custom(TypeFactory.java:213)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 56 more
```

The stacktrace implies `ClassNotFound` but I've added dependency `'org.threeten:threetenbp:0.9'`

**My Question**

How can I persist `java.time.LocalDateTime` in JPA with Hibernate using usertype?

Comment: Try running mvn dependency:tree and check whether you have multiple versions of threetenbp in your dependency hierarchy.

Comment: Turns out. I was not getting threetenbp dependencies although I tried downloaded many times. Working now. :)

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because you are using the wrong type. You should use `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentLocalDateTime` instead of `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threetenbp.PersistentLocalDateTime` for the JSR-310 classes.
You don't need the `org.threeten:threetenbp:0.9` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread but since it doesn't have an answer, here's a suggestion.
Since Hibernate doesn't support it you need to implement a user type as shown in [this](http://blog.progs.be/550/java-time-hibernate) example.

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
import org.hibernate.usertype.EnhancedUserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;

public class LocalDateTimeUserType implements EnhancedUserType, Serializable {

    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = new int[]{Types.TIMESTAMP};

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return LocalDateTime.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        }
        if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }
        LocalDateTime dtx = (LocalDateTime) x;
        LocalDateTime dty = (LocalDateTime) y;
        return dtx.equals(dty);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return object.hashCode();
    }


    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Object timestamp = StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeGet(resultSet, names, session, owner);
        if (timestamp == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Date ts = (Date) timestamp;
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(ts.getTime());
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, null, index, session);
        } else {
            LocalDateTime ldt = ((LocalDateTime) value);
            Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
            Date timestamp = Date.from(instant);
            StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, timestamp, index, session);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToSQLString(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public String toXMLString(Object object) {
        return object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromXMLString(String string) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hibernate 5 [added support for JSR310](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844)

Comment: The question was about using jadira, not about how to write your own user type.