# Current date time in Java using Joda time in mySQL type date time format

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate and trying to make the string that will hold the current date time for the database insert using `session.save()` method. I need the String object as output in mySQL date time format. Something like this:

```
`System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parseDateTime(new DateTime().toString()));`
```

Just a call out that the about statement doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to create a string representation of the DateTime object, you should just store it directly.

For an example, see [How to persist JSR 310 java.time.LocalDateTime in JPA with Hibernate using usertype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820492/how-to-persist-jsr-310-java-time-localdatetime-in-jpa-with-hibernate-using-usert)